# Production Laravel App stopped working on Azure due to constant timeout postgresql

Tags: laravel, postgresql, azure, timeout

I didn't have any issues until today, for some reason which I don't understand  my web app on azure is giving me a timeout exception when connecting to a postgresql server:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (7)
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired (SQL: select "lid" from "my_table" where "lid" = 2131)
Previous exceptions
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired (7)
```

I initially thought it was because azure server changed the ip and I was blocking through postgresql allowed host configuration but after I've opened everything it still doesn't work.

I'm even able to connect through my local server running laravel (:8000) but when I try through production it doesn't work. I don't get it, just keeps timing out.

Update:If I change the table it works for a while but then starts timeout

[image]

Update: I'm trying to connect using pg_connect and I have the same issue. For some reason pg_connect started timing out today.

```
PHP Warning: pg_connect(): Unable to connect to Postgresql server: could not connect to server: Connection timed out. Is the server running on host "IP" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

If I use other servers we have to query the DB there are no issues including my local machine, and the azure web app only times out sometimes others is really quick to respond.

**Update**: I rolled back to a previous snapshot and it started working again even after putting the code back. After about one day it has reached the same time out issue so I assume it's an issue where there are no more outbound connections free. Shouldn't laravel close the connections ?

**Update**: Below is the port usage graph , I can't find anything wrong, not sure why postgresql connection starts timing out. The 0 section is when I had to do a snapshot recovery in order to temporary stop the timeouts.

[image]

Comment: Setup an alert for "Active Connections" on Azure alerts?

Comment: @jminkler: I've added the graph for port usage, do you see anything wrong ? It went to 0 when I had to do a snapshot rollback and then the time out was fixed temporarly

Comment: are you using any connection pooling pg_pool etc?

Comment: Have you seen this discussion? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8339b3ec-db96-4ca0-b89d-d044ed4bd702/postgresql-database-connection-randomly-times-out?forum=AzureDatabaseforPostgreSQL